# Materialize entities from SqlDataReader

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to materialize (within the Entity Framework) Entities from a standard SQL Data Reader?

I am writing specific SQL that is passed to the server using EntityConnection.StoreConnection. Thsi returns a standard Data Reader containing rows should be materialized as Entities.

I suppose one workaround is to create a Entity-returning Function Import that can run my arbitrary SQL, but I wonder if there is a neater way?

Regards

Lee

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained why you want to do this. If your goal is just to write custom SQL, this isn't how I would go about it.

Comment: Hi Craig

Yes, it is to write custom SQL. We have our own Domain-specific lanaguage for querying entities and we need translate that into SQL. I first considered using Entity-SQL, but however it creates massively complex SQL and so my intention is to generate the SQL instead.

Lee

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify custom SQL for your entity results, you should use either a [defining query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982038%28VS.100%29.aspx) ([see also](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/05/14/how-why-use-definingquery-element.aspx)) (supported by the EF, but not the GUI designer, at least in v1) or a [stored proc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx).

**Update:** In EF v4, [you can use `ExecuteStoreQuery<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/11/07/tip-41-how-to-execute-t-sql-directly-against-the-database.aspx) and get materialization of arbitrary entities for free.

Comment: There are two problems with that method:
1) I would have to create a new type of Entity - I want to create materialize entities of the type I already have.
2) It looks as though I cannot specvify the defining query dynamically

Comment: You can pass SQL (or a fragment thereof) to a proc.